# QueryDSL Enum Error converting data type varchar to float

Tags: java, sql-server, enums, querydsl

I'm having an issue with executing a query built using QueryDSL on SQL 2008.

I have an Enumerated field on my entity bean:

```
@Column(name="APPROVAL_BY")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private ApprovalTypeEnum approvedBy;
```

And I'm using it to filter my result set within a querydsl BooleanBuilder:

```
builder.and(qPositionToIndividualRelationship.approvedBy.stringValue().in(filter.getSelectedApprovalTypeList()));
```

Which then results in the following clause in the executed SQL:

```
str(positionto1_.APPROVAL_BY) in ('Value1' , 'Value2')
```

When there are no results to return this is fine and no error is encountered, however when there are results I get the following:

> [SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions] SQL Error: 8114, SQLState: S0005
>   [SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions] Error converting data type varchar to float.

If I manually execute the query without the parse using str() the query works fine and returns the results I expect.

Does anyone know:

1. Why the SqlServer dialect decides to parse using str()?
2. Is there a way to prevent this?

Cheers

Comment: SQL doesn't do anything with regards to requiring you to use `STR()`.  That would be your ORM doing its own thing, which makes zero sense by the way.  STR() string-ifys numeric fields. It would never contain anything like 'Value1'.  I would guess your issue is some type or configuration within your QueryDSL layer that thinks the field is numeric, thus the conversation and trying to use STR() in SQL.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your response - yeah I didn't think it was SQL itself doing anything, it can only execute what it's given and I understand that the issue has to do with how the ORM interprets and then passes the statement through for execution. That being said, like you say it makes no sense why it's using STR() on a clearly defined "String" typed enum field....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, my understanding of whats happening here is that calling .stringValue() is inserting the STR() in the query, not getting the string value of the enum like perhaps you are intending. not really sure if there is a way of doing that since it is dealing with a 'Path' type object.

I think queryDSL really intends for you to compare enums with enums, or objects with objects. it will then handle the conversion so you dont need to worry about it.

ie.
`builder.and(qPositionToIndividualRelationship.approvedBy.in(filter.getSelectedApprovalTypeList()));`

where `filter.getSelectedApprovalTypeList()` returns a list of your `ApprovalTypeEnum`